# Is Laplacian a surjective operator?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-operators, laplacian

For  a closed  manifold the  laplacian is  almost  surjective  operator since the index of $\Delta$ is  zero  and  there is  no  a  non  constant harmonic  function. So the  codimension of  the image  of  $\Delta$ is equal to $1$.

Now  assume  that  $M$  is  an  open  manifold(non compact  without boundary).  What  type  of  results  exist  for  the  image  of  $\Delta$. Is it  surjective? Is the  codimension of  its  image  finite?

Comment: If $M\cup\partial M$ is compact, the Dirichlet problem is solvable and therefore $\Delta$ is surjective on reasonnable functional spaces.

Comment: You should be more precise about the function spaces. For example, $\Delta:C^\infty(\mathbb R^2) \to C^\infty(\mathbb R^2)$ is surjective but $\Delta:C^2(\mathbb R^2) \to C^0(\mathbb R^2)$ is not.

Comment: $\Delta$ on $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ is not surjective either because $0$ is in the spectrum.